# A Property equivalent to being a closed map

Tags: general-topology

Please, I like you to view this statement and tell if I'm doing something wrong.

**Proposition:** A function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces is closed if and only if for all $A \subseteq X$ then $\overline{f(A)} \subseteq f(\overline{A})$.

**Proof:** ($\Rightarrow$) Let be $B \subseteq X$ closed. As $B$ is closed, then $B = \overline{B}$, but as $f$ is closed then $f(B) \subseteq Y$ is closed, then $\overline{f(B)} \subseteq f(\overline{B})$.

Comment: That's fine. It's the other direction that's the main point.

Comment: I have thought this to prove the other direction.

($\Leftarrow$) If for all $A \subseteq X$ such that $\overline{f(A)} \subseteq f(\overline{A})$, then

$$ f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)}) \subseteq f^{-1}(f(\overline{A})) \subseteq \overline{A} $$

then $f^{-1}$ is closed.

Is there any mistake in this argument?

Comment: You shouldn't show that $f^{-1},$ but that $f$, is closed.

Comment: Yeah, my idea was try to find some relation between $f$ and $f^{-1}$, but I was in a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $(\Rightarrow)$ we assume that $f$ is closed and let $A\subseteq X$. Then note that
$
A\subseteq\bar A
$
implies
$$
f(A)\subseteq f(\bar A)\tag{1}
$$
But now (1) implies
$$
\overline{f(A)}\subseteq\overline{f(\bar{A}})\tag{2}
$$
Since $f$ is closed, $\overline{f(\bar{A})}=f(\bar{A})$ so $(2)$ implies $\overline{f(A)}\subseteq f(\bar{A})$ as required.

To prove $(\Leftarrow)$, suppose that $\overline{f(A)}\subseteq f(\bar{A})$ whenever $A\subseteq X$. To show that $f$ is closed, let $C\subseteq X$ be closed. Then note that
$$
f(C)\subseteq\overline{f(C)}\tag{3}
$$
Moreover, by assumption we have
$$
\overline{f(C)}\subseteq f(\bar{C})=f(C)\tag{4}
$$
Putting (3) and (4) together gives $\overline{f(C)}=f(C)$ so $f(C)$ is closed. Hence $f$ is closed.